# Convert Unicode Object to Python Dict

Tags: python, serialization, json

A request object that I'm dealing with has the following value for the key "address":

```
  u"{u'city': u'new-york', u'name': u'Home', u'display_value': u'2 Main Street'}"
```

I need to operate on this unicode object as a dictionary.  Unfortunately, json.loads() fails because it is not a json compatible object.

Is there any way to deal with this?  Do I have to work with the the json.JSONDecoder object?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
>>> ast.literal_eval(u"{u'city': u'new-york', u'name': u'Home', u'display_value': u'2 Main Street'}")
{u'city': u'new-york', u'name': u'Home', u'display_value': u'2 Main Street'}
```

Comment: thanks, search for many posts, and most are so complex, this is the most tidy one